# Using plain TeX to get text flowing around included images

Tags: graphics, plain-tex

I'm looking to have a page full of text, with an embedded image aligned left, another embedded image aligned right, the two images not necessarily at the same height.

Here is an image showing the sort of thing I mean.

[image]

I freely recognise that this is probably stupidly simple and that I've missed the obvious, and I apologise in advance if that's the case.  I thought this would be a simple question, but I've been searching for some time, and my search-fu has failed me entirely.  I have a poor solution in LaTeX, but it is heavily restricted, and I'm hoping that perhaps plain TeX will let me do what I'm after.  I would normally include all the things I've tried looking for, but there are too many, and it's now all a fog.

I'm using absolutely vanilla TeX on Ubuntu 14 (soon to be upgraded through 16 to 18).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This isn't really stupidly simple, so don't be embarrassed.  A few TUGboat articles on the subject:  [TeX Does Windows: A Progress Report](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb08-1/tb17knutsat.pdf), [TeX Does Windows--The Conclusion](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb08-2/tb18hoenig.pdf), [Comment on "TeX Does Windows"](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb08-2/tb18fox.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is assuming pdftex for the image inclusion but otherwise is just using the `\parshape` tex primitive to specify the cutouts.

`\parshape` takes a list of pairs, left indent and length of line segment.

[image]

```
\def\z{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten elevel twelve}
\def\zz{Red \z. Green yellow \z. Blue black orange\z}
\def\zzz{\zz. \zz. \zz}

\parshape 29
0pt \hsize 0pt \hsize 0pt \hsize 0pt \hsize 0pt \hsize 0pt \hsize 0pt \hsize  0pt \hsize
.3\hsize .7\hsize .3\hsize .7\hsize .3\hsize .7\hsize .3\hsize .7\hsize .3\hsize .7\hsize 
.3\hsize .7\hsize .3\hsize .7\hsize 
.3\hsize .4\hsize .3\hsize .4\hsize .3\hsize .4\hsize 
0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 
0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 0pt .7\hsize 
0pt \hsize
\noindent
\hbox to 0pt{\vbox to 0pt{%
\vskip6\baselineskip
\pdfximage  width .25\hsize{man.png}
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage
\vss}\hss}%
\hbox to 0pt{\hskip.75\hsize
\vbox to 0pt{%
\vskip14\baselineskip
\pdfximage  width .25\hsize{man2.png}
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage
\vss}\hss}%
\indent
\zzz. \zz. \zzz. \zz. \zzz. \zz.
\zzz. \zzz. 

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I've copied the text, but I'm getting "Undefined control sequence." for \pdfximage ...

Comment: @RiderOfGiraffes as I said, I assumed pdftex. You gave no indication of which tex engine you were using, and pdftex is by far the most common. What are you using?

Comment: @RiderOfGiraffes if you are using luatex or xetex for example, equivalent image inclusion commands exist, one of the benefits of using latex is that it can hide these difference behind a common i`\includegraphics` interface, but you asked for plain TeX.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me that the statement about "pdftex" was critical.  I'm just typing "tex <filename>" on the command line.  (a) How can I find out what engine that is?  (b) What command would you recommend I use instead?  I'm on vanilla Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I asked for plain text because my *extensive* attempts to use LaTex for this have failed.  It seems to be impossible to have images offset but overlapping in vertical placement.  If you can tell me how to get images in LaTex without them requiring paragraphs all to themselves, and with vertical placement overlap, then that would also be useful (although not for this specific task). ... and thank you.

Comment: Using pdftex has worked!  I now have to play with the placements and size of cutouts, but I can do that.

Comment: @RiderOfGiraffes oh it would be easier and more portable in latex but this is a plain tex question now:-) (well the cutout part would be the same but image inclusion is easier.)

Comment: Two things. (a) How in LaTeX can I get this effect as per the example layout I gave in the question?  And (b) Should we move this to chat, as is being suggested to me?

Comment: if you put `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` at the top of the file, and replace `\bye` at the end by `\end{document}` then the above would work in pdflatex.

Comment: It does.  OK, I need to start afresh asking the different question.  I want a TeX or LaTex document where I can get images that overlap in vertical placement. Ideally I'd like them to float to position, but that appears to be impossible in LaTex, so I've resigned myself to doing it "by hand".  If someone can show me how to float images into place as per the example layout I'd be very grateful.

Comment: the site format really doesn't work if you ask new questions in comments. New questions should be asked as  well new questions. But you would need to define "float" and "into place" in any question, what causes the images to go to those lines and overlap as opposed to say coming after the paragraph. @RiderOfGiraffes

Comment: I'll ask a new question ... I need to take time to phrase it properly.  This solution (thanks again) will work, but there *has* to be a better way to accomplish my end goal.  Previous attempts at asking the question have left people saying "Nope, can't do that."  But I'll try again.

Comment: New question asked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527282/getting-text-to-flow-around-images-in-either-tex-or-latex

Comment: @RiderOfGiraffes actually I think you just asked the same question again, as I  was just writing there before I saw your comment here.